# 404 Not found ( MVC 5 ) after deploying web APP

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, http-status-code-404

I am facing some issue after deploying a App.
i have an asp.net MVC 5 project.

Controller Name:ProjectsController
View Name :Projects.cshtml
ActionResult (In controller) : ExecuteScripts

**When i compile and execute from my system, it works fine.The controller Action method is executed successfully.**

**Issue :** 
After deploying in IIS, when i try to access that website, website is accessible and all data is displayed properly. But when i try to click a button named Execute, which will call an Action named "ExecuteScripts" in Controller, i am getting below error.

**http://10.xx.xx.xxx/Projects/ExecuteScripts?finalTests=CreateID%3B+SearchID%3B+CreateORDER%3B+SearchOrder%3B+&selectedproject=Test1**

**Background:**
I have a controller named "ProjectsController" and a ActionResult named "ExecuteScripts" which takes two parameters which is passed from view named Projects.cshtml.

I have this code in View, Projects.cshtml.Up on clicking Execute button this will be called.

```
  $.ajax({
  url: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/Projects/ExecuteScripts',
            data: {
                finalTests: finalTests,
                selectedproject: selectedproject
            },
            success: function () {
                alert('Triggered tests. Will start in few minutes.');
            }
        });
```

Can anyone let me know what is going wrong.

Kindly let me know if you need more info.

Thanks,
VVP

Comment: Use `url: '@Url.Action("ExecuteScripts", "Projects")',` so you urls are correctly generated

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your calling wroung url in production so your getting 404 Error. change url as

```
url : "~/Projects/ExecuteScripts"
```

Or

```
@Url.Action("ExecuteScripts", "Projects")
```